# Calling 15 Web services sequentially

Tags: java, performance, web-services

Scenario is that there are 15 web services which I need to invoke to invoke and the consolidated response needs to be send to another system .My query is these 15 services need to invoked for around 1000 requests(because there are 1000 sales people whose data is fetched from these 15 web services). What would be efficient implementation of this . If I create several threads for different sales people then might the services which I am invoking are not thread safe . So should i call the services sequentially ? But that would degrade the performance .

Answer (score 2):

Web services, by their nature, are meant to handle concurrent requests. You only need to worry about thread safety within your client application and can safely assume the web services you are calling are thread safe.

Comment: I tried creating a webservice which was not Thread safe . A simple program which increased a counter variable and exposed that as a web service . And my client program created two threads and incremented that variable using threads . The state of that variable did not remain consistent on different executions . Hence I believe that web services need to be implemented in a thread safe manner then only I can call them using threads . Please suggest in case I am wrong

Comment: Web services can handle concurrent requests, but as you have demonstrated the implementation may not be thread safe. If you fear their implementation is not thread safe, you have to pay the performance cost or raise it as a defect/feature.

Comment: Most modern web services are designed to be stateless, which by definition makes them threadsafe.  The service you described is not stateless.  In that case, the shared data (your counter) needs to be updated atomically.  The code that increments the counter should be synchronized.

Comment: This service I have demonstrated is just an example . I was thinking if the developer of service has not taken into consideration thread safety so might be it could cause problems . So while invoking any webservice this might be an issue or we should just invoke the service with several threads and take by default that those services would be thread safe ?

Comment: See pimaster's response. Any decent web service will be thread safe.  If it isn't, it would mean the service could not have more than one client calling it at any time, including clients on separate machines. Imagine if the google search API were not thread safe! All publicized web services in general use are indeed thread safe. Hope this has helped.